# How to stop prettier from formatting strings?

Tags: javascript, prettier

Is there any way to stop prettier from formatting my strings in backticks ?

I have already added `"printWidth": 1000` to `.prettierrc` file.
but it will apply this setting to all of my files and i only want to
apply this setting to strings in backticks

[image]

Comment: All available options here : https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

Comment: If you only want to apply strings in backticks, I think you can use other tools like eslint.

Comment: I don't think there is a "global" way to ignore strings, but you can add `/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */` on top of the file. If these files have a specific file type/name you can also disable it for files matching a specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignoring the strings, [here is the docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript)

To ignore line of code use: `// prettier-ignore`

Answer (score 0):

You can tell prettier to ignore a file or a specific line from a file.

1. **Disable Prettier for specific files:** You can create a file called `.prettierignore` in the root directory of your project. This file uses Git ignore syntax to specify which files or folders Prettier should ignore. For example, if you want to exclude all JavaScript files from formatting, you would add `*.js` to the `.prettierignore` file.
2. **Use comments to disable Prettier:** You can add a comment to the top of a file to disable Prettier for that specific file. The comment syntax will depend on your editor or IDE. For example, in Visual Studio Code, you can use the following comment:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
```